# Swift iOS- How to Add Button to the outside a CollectionView Cell

Tags: uibutton, frame, uicollectionviewcell, cgrect, bounds

1. I want to get a deleteButton that is a delete image to sit on the outside of a collectionViewCell (it can be partially inside).

[image]

2. I looked at other SO answers and they said just play with the button's frame's Rect's `x & y` values which I did. When I set the `x & y` values to `0,0` I get:

   ```
    class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    var deleteButton: UIButton!
    var deleteButtonImg: UIImage!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: frame.size.width/4, height: frame.size.width/4))

    deleteButtonImg = UIImage(named: "delete-icon")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    deleteButton.setImage(deleteButtonImg, for: .normal)
    deleteButton.tintColor = UIColor.red

    contentView.addSubview(deleteButton)
    }
   ```

[image]

3. When I try to set the the Rect's `x & y` to `-10,-10` the deleteButton gets clipped inside the cell's imageView. I don't have `clipsToBounds` set.

   ```
    deleteButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: -10, y: -10, width: frame.size.width/4, height: frame.size.width/4))
   ```

[image]

I even tried setting `clipToBounds` to `false` but I get the same effect as pic # 3.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.imageView.image = myImageArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = false

        return cell
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: try setting `deleteButton.clipsToBounds = false` in custom cell

Comment: @Shankar BS thanks for the assistance :) In "class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell" I tried deleteButton.clipsToBounds = false and then tried imageView.clipsToBounds = false but neither worked :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was inside storyboard I had a:

```
CollectionView
      -CustomCell (type collectionViewCell)
           -imageView
```

Under the Attributes Inspector, in the Drawing section, all 3 of these have the property `clipsToBounds`.

I overlooked the fact that I had clipsToBounds set to false (unchecked) on the imageView but set to true (checked) on the CustomCell and the CollectionView.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

If anyone else has this problem make sure you `uncheck` clipsToBounds on the collectionView, collectionViewCell, and the imageView.

Comment: great answer, just a side note - the clipToBounds on the collectionview will clip the top of the x button, and the clipToBounds on the cell will clip the leading side of the x button..

Comment: @Eyzuky thanks for the additional info. Everything helps!

Comment: clip to bounds in the custom cell needs also to be false.

Answer (score 2):

okay u can do like below, first create a xib file and replace default view with collection view cell and set up like below,

[image]

in the above image set the class name to `CustomCell` (In my case) and place image view (green ) and button (blue).

and in `View controller`,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     //register the nib to collectionview
    self.aColectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL")
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 40
}

//cell creation as u are doing
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:CustomCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CUSTOM_CELL", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
     //set the image for custom cell

    return cell
}

//return the required size
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 150)
}
```

and output like below,

[image]

and in custom cell class, u add any other features like action for a button and other views related code

```
class CustomCell:UICollectionViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var deleteButton: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


  //other view related code
}
```

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow. I'm about to fall asleep. I'll let you know how it works. Thanks  Btw the 2nd pic didn't show

Comment: I found the answer, in storyboards I had the imageView's clipsToBounds unchecked but the collectionViewCell and the collectionView's clipsToBounds checked. I'm going to up vote your answer for the effort and because it's a great alternative! Thanks again :)